# Fedora Server NSlookup error when running DNS

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, fedora, nslookup, fedora-server

So I have 2 VMs (Fedora 24 Server and its Client).

I am trying to run DNS in Server and get output in Client.

The DNS of my client is IP of Server, All of them are on same Class of network with is 192.168.95.0/24

IP of Server - 192.168.95.1
IP of Client - 192.168.95.50

DNS is ON in Server and firewall is disable in both VM

I have changed named.conf file as well Check Screenshot  [named.conf file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KeSea.png)

I am getting >>this error while passing command in Fedora Client ->[Error Image in Client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WE6L5.png)

Please someone assist me.

Answer (score 1):

## Try to isolate the issue :

### Server side

All your config files are correct ?

- Run `named-checkconf`

Do you see some errors in the logs ?

- Run `journalctl -u named`

Could you resolve on the DNS server (not the client) ?

- Run `dig @127.0.0.1 YOUR-LOCAL-ADDRESS` or `nslookup YOUR-LOCAL-ADDRESS 127.0.0.1`
- Run `dig @127.0.0.1 google.com` or `nslookup google.com 127.0.0.1`

### Client side

The DNS address is correct in your network settinfgs ? If you try to resolve `google.com` ?

- Run with default DNS `nslookup google.com`
- Force your DNS server `nslookup google.com 192.168.95.1`

Comment: So I figured out what was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

My primary NIC PORT was also enabled in Server-side which was creating conflict.

After disabling both side ports I got my nslookup command working

Thank you for your help.